# Should I write new unit tests for classes that I create during the refactor phase of TDD?

Tags: unit-testing

I have created my unit tests and my class and I got everything to work as quickly as possible and I have a green bar and many tests.

Now I want to refactor and make it good. Part of the refactoring that I want to do is create a new class that SUT will rely on because I realize that I had different levels of abstraction in the same class. Now the existing tests will cover the new class completely but I am unsure whether to move the tests to a new TestClass that tests the new class, duplicate them (although they will be slightly different) in both or don't bother because the original class is the external API and the new class is a private member variable.

Answer (score 2):

You just run into one of the great advantages of unit testing: `refactoring protection`, which means that if you have a good suite of unit tests that cover `all functionalities and corner cases` of your class methods, you can safely refactor the class in whatever way you want, as long as you don't modify the `public interface` of that class.

The new `helper` class you are planning to add doesn't need tests on its own, as it will be indirectly tested through the original class. However, if you plan to export the `helper` class to other classes, then you might consider adding tests for the `helper`, to reduce the overhead of debugging failing tests on the other classes (as you know that the `helper` is OK).

Answer (score 0):

Not testing private methods is an accepted (but somewhat controversial) best practice.

You want your test suite to ensure that your public API's function correctly and as documented - not the actual implementation.

So, as long as your refactoring does not add any additional functionality, change parameters in public methods, etc. then you do not need to add new tests in the refactor phase.

Comment: I am not talking about creating private methods. I know not to test private methods. I am talking about creating a brand new class that the first relies on.

Comment: i got that, but if the new class does not have any public methods then no. If it does have public methods that are not part of an API than its up to the developer. Sometimes testing the methods of class A, is enough to cover class B.